# choice of heat sink (thermal resistance)

Tags: heatsink

I want to calculate the thermal resistance resistance for my board:[image]

I found on the amplifier datasheet how I should calculate.
[image]

I found a value of -0.389 °C/W which seems wrong to me. I don't know if I took the right value to calculate the resistance.

to power the amplifier I used 3 power supplies (2 power supply (+ -100v) and 1 power supply (+ -15v)

Comment: It's called thermal resistance and not "resistance". For an EE site, "resistance" will be taken to mean "electrical resistance" and confuses the issue. Please show the working of how you arrived at -0.389 °C/W.

Comment: I will correct. Thank you

Comment: @ChàiMà I notice that the circuit has two PA107 devices - just to make sure, this isn't for an audio amplifier, is it? There are likely to be better devices for that application that don't cost [$300+ each](https://www.mouser.co.uk/ProductDetail/Apex-Microtechnology/PA107DP?qs=TiOZkKH1s2QZuSYT1Lb%2FVw==&vip=1&gclid=CjwKCAiAt9z-BRBCEiwA_bWv-Puv8YiJwbfSAqeXFLI1UiYNSV29VS1pTeuuvz87kk2_VQx1oKAG0hoCPEUQAvD_BwE).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result will be positive for practical passive setups.

A negative thermal resistance for your heatsink to ambient calculation means you are trying to power the device at more than its internal thermal resistance can handle. That's why it wants you to have a negative thermal resistance to ambient.

The solutions may include

- reduce the power that you're dissipating in the device
- see if the device has an alternative package with a lower R<sub>thJC</sub>
- use a lower ambient temperature
- if necessary mount the device on a Peltier to reduce its case temperature